# React Native Bridge Library for existing Objective C Framework which depends on other iOS Frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

1. I have an Objective-C Framework, which depends on other third party Frameworks through CocoaPods.

   `i.e A-->B,C,D`
2. I created a `react-native-create-library` bridge which wraps the code around Objective-C Framework A.

   `i.e React_Native_A-->A-->B,C,D`
3. I tried creating an example app `Example_React_Native_A` which links the React_Native_A using the `react_native link` command. Hoping that it links to the other frameworks added using the CocoaPods.
4. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in this way. It won't even consider `React_Native_A-->A` link.

Is there any other way to generate the example app, so that it can link all the required frameworks i.e `A-->B,C,D`.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for the solution, the way is mentioned in the `RNNearBee.podspec` [here](https://github.com/Beaconstac/react-native-nearbee/blob/master/RNNearbee.podspec). The wrapper podspec depends on the version of the react as per the local machine installed version and then it depends on the original native podspec.